# Directus Api GET doesn't show changes instantly

Tags: directus

I use directus as my cms and I use the API together with an React app. Whenever I update an Item, the update is instantly shown in the Directus UI. However if I directly afterwards fetch the table, with rest or graphql, I get the old, non changed item. It takes up to 10 minutes to finally get the updated data.

I also used a different instance of directus, and there everything works perfectly and everything is instantly upadted when fetching directly afterwards..

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the wanted behaviour, the cache settings can be adapted. Initially the **CACHE_AUTO_PURGE** is set to false, which results in the data being cashed 5 minutes until the new changes can be fetched. Just set the CACHE_AUTO_PURGE to true, to always get the newest changes.

**CACHE_AUTO_PURGE**

> Automatically purge the data cache on actions that manipulate the data.
> [Directus Docs](https://docs.directus.io/self-hosted/config-options.html#cache)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using redis please disable it in the environment variable by setting CACHE_ENABLED = false

Comment: Where can I set that?

Comment: @PhilippFischer how do you setup directus? Do you selfhost or local setup?

Comment: If you run directus locally you can set that option in .env fine which stay inside root of api directory. If you use online service like railway or other cloud platform they have the option to set environment variable . Go and find that option and set it accordingly.

Comment: Please refer to this document if using docker compose https://docs.directus.io/self-hosted/docker-guide.html#example-docker-compose